# API host's rate-limit header not read properly

Tags: javascript, json, http-headers, cross-domain, fetch-api

Here is my code (not the entire code, but I think this is the only really relevant part):

```
const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const createThrottler = (limitHeader) => {
  let requestTimestamp = 0;
  let rateLimit = 0;
  return (requestHandler) => {
    return async (...params) => {
      const currentTimestamp = Number(Date.now());
      if (currentTimestamp < requestTimestamp + rateLimit) {
        const timeOut = rateLimit - (currentTimestamp - requestTimestamp);
        requestTimestamp = Number(Date.now()) + timeOut;
        await timer(timeOut)
      }
      requestTimestamp = Number(Date.now());
      const response = await requestHandler(...params);
      if (!rateLimit > 0) {
        rateLimit = Math.floor((60 / response.headers.get(limitHeader)) * 1000);
      }
      console.log(limitHeader);
      console.log(rateLimit);
      return response;
    }
  }
}

const throttle = createThrottler("X-***-Ratelimit");
const throttleFetch = throttle(fetch);

function getRelease(idFiltered) {
  return throttleFetch(`https://api.***.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': '***/0.1',
    },
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
        return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
      } else {
        const id = data.id;
        const delimiter = document.getElementById("delimiter").value || "|";
        const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : [];
        const barcode = data.identifiers.filter(id => id.type === 'Barcode')
          .map(barcode => barcode.value);
        var formattedBarcode = barcode.join(delimiter);
        const country = data.country || 'Unknown';
        const genres = data.genres || [];
        const formattedGenres = genres.join(delimiter);
        const labels = data.labels ? data.labels.map(label => label.name) : [];
        const formattedLabels = labels.join(delimiter);
        const catno = data.labels ? data.labels.map(catno => catno.catno) : [];
        const formattedCatNo = catno.join(delimiter);
        const styles = data.styles || [];
        const formattedStyles = styles.join(delimiter);
        const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist
          .map(track => track.title) : [];
        const formattedTracklist = tracklist.join(delimiter);
        const year = data.year || 'Unknown';
        const format = data.formats ? data.formats.map(format => format.name) : [];
        const qty = data.formats ? data.formats.map(format => format.qty) : [];
        const descriptions = data.formats ? data.formats
          .map(descriptions => descriptions.descriptions) : [];
        const preformattedDescriptions = descriptions.toString()
          .replace('"', '""').replace(/,/g, ', ');
        const formattedDescriptions = '"' + preformattedDescriptions + '"';
        console.log(idFiltered,
          artists,
          format,
          qty,
          formattedDescriptions,
          formattedLabels,
          formattedCatNo,
          country,
          year,
          formattedGenres,
          formattedStyles,
          formattedBarcode,
          formattedTracklist
        )

        return [idFiltered,
          artists,
          format,
          qty,
          formattedDescriptions,
          formattedLabels,
          formattedCatNo,
          country,
          year,
          formattedGenres,
          formattedStyles,
          formattedBarcode,
          formattedTracklist
        ];
      }
    });
}
```

But the "X-***-Ratelimit" header is clearly not being read correctly, as when I do

```
      console.log(limitHeader);
      console.log(rateLimit);
```

I initially get back

> object

and thereafter

> X-***-Ratelimit
> Infinity

From the host's documentation:

> We attach the following headers to responses to help you track your rate limit use:

> X-***-Ratelimit: The total number of requests you can make in a one minute window.

> X-***-Ratelimit-Used : The number of requests you’ve made in your existing rate limit window.

> X-***-Ratelimit-Remaining: The number of remaining requests you are able to make in the existing rate limit window.

Any help please? TIA.

Edit: amazingly, I managed to greatly increase the rate-limit by getting my app authenticated thusly:

```
headers: {
  'User-Agent': '***/0.1',
  'Authorization': '*** key=***, secret=***',
},
```

However, I just took the key and secret from the site documentation, and I now get back this JSON response:

> message - "Invalid consumer key/secret. Please register an app before making requests."

Edit2: OK, I worked out how to register my app now. I'm proceeding to further tests.

Edit3: the rate-limit in effect from the host is much better now, but my app is still not reading the header from the response correctly, so `limitHeader` is still coming back as "Infinity", instead of some meaningful/appropriate value.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where are you running this code (browser, nodejs, …), what is `fetch`? Are you doing a cross-domain request?

Comment: I'm running it in the browser. It's just plain JavaScript. As far as `fetch` goes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. I'm not sure about the cross-domain request aspect; not sure how to tell TBH.

Comment: 2) I think perhaps it is a cross-domain request, because my client is requesting resources from another domain (the target API).

Comment: Does the API use CORS? Does it send a [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `access-control-allow-headers Content-Type, authorization, User-Agent, Private-Auth-Secret, ***-UID`. The problem is that my app is not reading the `ratelimit` response headers correctly.  They are being supplied; I can view them in the console, but `response.headers.get(limitHeader)` doesn't work and I don't understand why. Isn't that the correct syntax to get a given header and store it as a variable? I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: `expose-headers` (the ones you can read from the response) is the relevant header, not the `allow-headers` one (the ones you can send in a request).

Comment: OK? I don't really understand what you're telling me to do? Clearly I need to change something as it's not reading the rate-limit correctly. In the console it shows `x-***-ratelimit` and that's just what I have in my code. I even tried following the same capitalisation in case it was a caps issue but it made no odds. Edit: in `createThrottler`, I'm passing in `limitHeader`, right? And `const response = await requestHandler(...params);` gets the response from the host, correct? So why doesn't `response.headers.get(limitHeader)` work as intended in that method?

Comment: I tried using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: <header-name>`, but that didn't work either. It strongly seems to me that I am getting the *header name* back, whereas I want to target the actual value I need, by supplying the header name, but I am completely stumped as to what I need to change.

Comment: [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) needs to be set by the API server. If it doesn't, there's nothing you can do about that. `x-***-ratelimit` is not a default [safelisted response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header).

Comment: So, you're saying my client can't possibly read data, even though it's right there in the console? I'm sceptical that that can be correct, to be honest. I really think we are talking at cross-purposes. All I want to do is read the `rate-limit` value that is already being supplied by the host and input it into my app. I don't see any reason why that should not be possible. Do you need me to add a screenshot? Edit: I added a screenshot. I really don't believe it's impossible for my app to read that value.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Not everything that you can inspect in the devtools can be accessed by javascript - think http-only cookies, cross-domain iframes or failed CORS requests for other examples.

Comment: By the way, I don't really know why you are talking about it being "set by the API server". I want to read it, not set it.

Comment: Well then don't believe me, I can't change how it works. The server needs to send the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-ratelimit` alongside the `x-ratelimit: somevalue` to allow a cors client to read the ratelimit value. Open an issue with the API provider - if they already support CORS, they're probably happy to add that header as well.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, it's just that I'm not convinced we are talking about the same thing. But yes, I definitely will open an issue with the API provider. It seems completely crazy that they would supply data to hep you connect to their service, but then block it from being accessed by any program, and restrict it to human eyes. That seems very unhelpful. Surely it should be possible for my app to programmatically query its own limits.

Comment: Well it's not that *they* blocked it… it's just that the browser blocks everything by default, and the API provider explicitly needs to *allow* access to non-sensitive headers.

Comment: I see, right. Well, sorry for my scepticism, but I have been genuinely amazed how difficult it is just to read such a value. Oh well, 'back to the drawing board' I guess. Thanks for the advice.